# Updating the master page when the control is within an update panel on the content page. i am trying lot but not get success?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit, master-pages

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Master.settxtvalue.Text = Me.TextBox1.Text
    Me.Button1 = TryCast(Me.Master.FindControl("mdlpp").FindControl("Button1"), Button)

End Sub


Public ReadOnly Property settxtvalue() As TextBox
    Get
        Return Me.TextBox18
    End Get
End Property
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that directly, You have to use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript() function which will inject java script statement which will execute when update panel get update. And add java script statment to find element to update and set it value.

Like following c# code convert it to VB and use

```
string strUpdate = "document.getElementById('" + Master.settxtvalue.ClientID + "').value = '" + Me.TextBox1.Text + "'";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, this.GetType(), "msupdate", strUpdate, true);
```

Here UpdatePanel1 is you update panel id. replace following line of your code

```
Master.settxtvalue.Text = Me.TextBox1.Text
```

with it.

This is VB version

```
Dim strUpdate As String = ("document.getElementById('" + Master.settxtvalue.ClientID & "').value = '") + [Me].TextBox1.Text & "'"
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, Me.[GetType](), "msupdate", strUpdate, True)
```